# How to mock database api?

Tags: python, database, mocking, tdd

Connecting database (even if it's an in-memory one) slows down my unittests (currently it took more than 5mins).

So I'm considering mocking the database api.

With the real database api, if there's any SQL syntax error or mistyped column name, it would raise exceptions.

While with a mock object, I can't think of any way to do this kind of check.

Is it possible to accomplish this with mock objects?

Comment: the same way you mock other api :)

Answer (score 3):

Sure! You can mock out db-api functions with your own custom functions that behave the way you want:

```
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import DatabaseError

mock_db_connection = Mock()

def mock_execute(query, params):
    if query == 'select firstname, lastname from student':
        return [('jim', 'brown')]
    elif query == 'select; firstname':
        raise DatabaseError('You have an error in your SQL syntax')

mock_db_connection.execute = mock_execute

# from this point, if you've patched out your db connection with the mock,
# you can make tests against connection.execute...
```

I'm assuming you're using the [mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/) library.

But really - 5 minutes isn't *that* long.  Personal preference, but I prefer to keep dependencies like this in - it helps you catch api errors.  You're never going to mock out an API perfectly, and a database isn't *that* severe an external dependency...

Comment: If running your unit tests takes 5 minutes you will not run them very often. Unit tests can never be too fast. Unit tests are not for catching "api errors". That's what integration and regression tests are for. If you use an external API and you want to make sure it behaves as expected, write a regression tests for it. This tests may be slower that a unit test, but you will also not need to run them very often, because the API and its behavior will not change all the time.

Comment: Hey, just so you know, you have an error on your last line. 'mock_db_connection.execute = mock_execute` should be on a new line indented on the left side.